# How can i plot text labels from one dataset at the y-axis positon based on data from a second data set?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have tried using reprex for the first time to create a reproducible example of my problem so hopefully it works correctly. So i am using two datasets in my ggplot, and i am trying to plot the countries policies above the number of coronavirus cases on the date which it was implemented on. I have chosen to focus on just one country from both the datasets for this example. I have considered trying to join them but there are not an equal amount of countries in both datasets so i am not entirely sure that would work.

So the aim is to have the policy names hovering just above the very top of the bar of the date they were implemented on. I believe they are currently in the right positions but i do not know how i can set the y-axis position in the geom text layer because the data for the cases is being used in the first layer.

Any advice on how to sort out this problem will be very helpful, thank you.

Edit: I plan on scaling this up to all the countries in my dataset, which is roughly 176, so doing it manually is not a realistic approach.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'scales'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:purrr':
#> 
#>     discard
#> The following object is masked from 'package:readr':
#> 
#>     col_factor

policy_uk <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                 X = c(1L,2L,3L,4L,5L,6L,7L,8L,
                       9L,10L,11L,12L,13L,14L,15L,16L,17L),
       CountryName = c("United Kingdom",
                       "United Kingdom","United Kingdom","United Kingdom","United Kingdom",
                       "United Kingdom","United Kingdom","United Kingdom",
                       "United Kingdom","United Kingdom","United Kingdom",
                       "United Kingdom","United Kingdom","United Kingdom",
                       "United Kingdom","United Kingdom","United Kingdom"),
              Date = c("2020-01-20","2020-01-31",
                       "2020-02-02","2020-02-03","2020-03-11","2020-03-11",
                       "2020-03-11","2020-03-16","2020-03-17","2020-03-17",
                       "2020-03-20","2020-03-22","2020-03-23","2020-03-23",
                       "2020-03-23","2020-03-26","2020-06-08"),
            policy = c("H2_Testing.policy",
                       "H3_Contact.tracing","H1_Public.information.campaigns",
                       "H5_Investment.in.vaccines","E3_Fiscal.measures",
                       "E4_International.support","H4_Emergency.investment.in.healthcare",
                       "C2_Workplace.closing","C3_Cancel.public.events",
                       "E2_Debt.contract.relief","E1_Income.support",
                       "C7_Restrictions.on.internal.movement","C1_School.closing",
                       "C4_Restrictions.on.gatherings","C6_Stay.at.home.requirements",
                       "C5_Close.public.transport","C8_International.travel.controls"),
             level = c(1,2,2,26014287.82,
                       32223318564.93,183360000,6444663712.99,1,1,1,2,1,3,4,2,
                       1,2)
)


uk_cases <- data.frame(
         stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                         countriesAndTerritories = c("United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom","United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom","United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom","United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom","United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom","United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom","United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom","United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom","United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom","United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom","United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom","United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom","United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom","United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom","United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom","United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom","United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom","United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom","United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom","United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom","United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom","United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom","United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom","United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom","United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom","United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom","United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom","United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom","United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom","United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom","United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom","United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom","United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom","United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom","United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom","United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom","United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom","United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom","United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom","United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom","United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom","United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom","United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom","United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom","United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom","United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom","United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom","United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom","United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom","United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom",
                                                     "United_Kingdom","United_Kingdom"),
                                         dateRep = c("2020-08-13",
                                                     "2020-08-12","2020-08-11",
                                                     "2020-08-10","2020-08-09",
                                                     "2020-08-08","2020-08-07",
                                                     "2020-08-06","2020-08-05",
                                                     "2020-08-04","2020-08-03",
                                                     "2020-08-02","2020-08-01",
                                                     "2020-07-31","2020-07-30",
                                                     "2020-07-29","2020-07-28",
                                                     "2020-07-27","2020-07-26",
                                                     "2020-07-25","2020-07-24",
                                                     "2020-07-23","2020-07-22",
                                                     "2020-07-21","2020-07-20",
                                                     "2020-07-19","2020-07-18",
                                                     "2020-07-17",
                                                     "2020-07-16","2020-07-15",
                                                     "2020-07-14","2020-07-13",
                                                     "2020-07-12","2020-07-11",
                                                     "2020-07-10","2020-07-09",
                                                     "2020-07-08","2020-07-07",
                                                     "2020-07-06","2020-07-05",
                                                     "2020-07-04","2020-07-03",
                                                     "2020-07-02","2020-07-01",
                                                     "2020-06-30","2020-06-29",
                                                     "2020-06-28","2020-06-27",
                                                     "2020-06-26","2020-06-25",
                                                     "2020-06-24","2020-06-23",
                                                     "2020-06-22","2020-06-21",
                                                     "2020-06-20",
                                                     "2020-06-19","2020-06-18",
                                                     "2020-06-17","2020-06-16",
                                                     "2020-06-15","2020-06-14",
                                                     "2020-06-13","2020-06-12",
                                                     "2020-06-11","2020-06-10",
                                                     "2020-06-09","2020-06-08",
                                                     "2020-06-07","2020-06-06",
                                                     "2020-06-05","2020-06-04",
                                                     "2020-06-03","2020-06-02",
                                                     "2020-06-01","2020-05-31",
                                                     "2020-05-30","2020-05-29",
                                                     "2020-05-28","2020-05-27",
                                                     "2020-05-26","2020-05-25",
                                                     "2020-05-24",
                                                     "2020-05-23","2020-05-22",
                                                     "2020-05-21","2020-05-20",
                                                     "2020-05-19","2020-05-18",
                                                     "2020-05-17","2020-05-16",
                                                     "2020-05-15","2020-05-14",
                                                     "2020-05-13","2020-05-12",
                                                     "2020-05-11","2020-05-10",
                                                     "2020-05-09","2020-05-08",
                                                     "2020-05-07","2020-05-06",
                                                     "2020-05-05","2020-05-04",
                                                     "2020-05-03","2020-05-02",
                                                     "2020-05-01","2020-04-30",
                                                     "2020-04-29","2020-04-28",
                                                     "2020-04-27",
                                                     "2020-04-26","2020-04-25",
                                                     "2020-04-24","2020-04-23",
                                                     "2020-04-22","2020-04-21",
                                                     "2020-04-20","2020-04-19",
                                                     "2020-04-18","2020-04-17",
                                                     "2020-04-16","2020-04-15",
                                                     "2020-04-14","2020-04-13",
                                                     "2020-04-12","2020-04-11",
                                                     "2020-04-10","2020-04-09",
                                                     "2020-04-08","2020-04-07",
                                                     "2020-04-06","2020-04-05",
                                                     "2020-04-04","2020-04-03",
                                                     "2020-04-02","2020-04-01",
                                                     "2020-03-31",
                                                     "2020-03-30","2020-03-29",
                                                     "2020-03-28","2020-03-27",
                                                     "2020-03-26","2020-03-25",
                                                     "2020-03-24","2020-03-23",
                                                     "2020-03-22","2020-03-21",
                                                     "2020-03-20","2020-03-19",
                                                     "2020-03-18","2020-03-17"),
                                           cases = c(1009L,1148L,816L,1062L,
                                                     758L,871L,950L,891L,
                                                     670L,928L,743L,771L,880L,
                                                     846L,763L,70L,371L,
                                                     421L,667L,731L,773L,751L,
                                                     793L,413L,493L,569L,
                                                     704L,772L,685L,726L,361L,
                                                     442L,565L,715L,693L,
                                                     597L,704L,555L,401L,579L,
                                                     602L,651L,617L,730L,
                                                     446L,649L,671L,721L,778L,
                                                     886L,896L,639L,687L,
                                                     986L,1027L,1013L,1102L,
                                                     1043L,822L,890L,1052L,
                                                     1017L,1199L,1158L,1099L,
                                                     721L,801L,1120L,1243L,
                                                     1356L,1484L,1441L,1079L,
                                                     1125L,1527L,1760L,1835L,
                                                     1672L,1624L,1364L,1527L,
                                                     2062L,2574L,2718L,3052L,
                                                     2589L,1838L,2079L,2526L,
                                                     2628L,3307L,3402L,
                                                     3586L,2329L,2157L,3063L,
                                                     3767L,3827L,3682L,3389L,
                                                     2982L,3229L,4737L,4966L,
                                                     5442L,4729L,4706L,3473L,
                                                     3748L,4970L,5158L,5487L,
                                                     4760L,4854L,3853L,4721L,
                                                     4956L,5292L,5065L,
                                                     4326L,4178L,3489L,3579L,
                                                     4313L,4858L,5131L,5450L,
                                                     5282L,3592L,4020L,4911L,
                                                     4868L,4913L,4514L,4273L,
                                                     2858L,2822L,3197L,3087L,
                                                     2692L,2375L,2338L,1378L,
                                                     1198L,1255L,1055L,999L,
                                                     769L,611L,442L)
                       )


uk_cases$dateRep <- as.Date(uk_cases$dateRep)
policy_uk$Date <- as.Date(policy_uk$Date)


ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(data = uk_cases, aes(x = dateRep, y = cases), stat = "identity") + 
  geom_text(data = policy_uk, aes(x = Date, y = 5000, label = policy)) +
  scale_x_date(breaks = "1 month", minor_breaks = "1 week", labels=date_format("%B"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-08-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I am sure there is a better solution, but you could quickly add a column for yLocation and manually specify the location that looks best to you since there are only 17 policies to plot. Then, reference that in your plot code. `policy_uk$yLocation <- c(500,1000,1500,2000,2500,3000,3500,4000,4500,4750,5000,5250,5000,4750,4500,4000,3500)`

Comment: To use the other dataset, you could join the two datasets and reference the cases for plotting y for your text. Unfortunately, The dates don't all match up so joining will result in some NAs in the joined dataset. They only way to get around that would be to round the dates (i.e., any date within a few days would be joined), or you could project the number of cases for the dates you have in the policy dataset. Here is the join that I used `policy_uk<-left_join(policy_uk,uk_cases[,c("Date","cases")])`.

Comment: @Tanner33. I maybe should have mentioned i plan on scaling this up to all of the countries in my dataset, so doing it manually would not be a realistic approach. I also considered joining the two larger datasets but the datasets do not have the same number of countries in them and i didn't think it would work.

Comment: I will post an answer with more code for the joining idea I was thinking of. It is going to be difficult to get something that works well for every situation, but this should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of rounding to the nearest date and using the case numbers from that date. The problem is that many policies have to be rounded to the same date (e.g., policies that happened before any cases were reported all get rounded to the first report) or dates with the same number of cases. To get around overlapping labels, you will need to deflect overlapping labels using something like `position = "dodge"`.

```
setDT(policy_uk)[, join_date := Date]
setDT(uk_cases)[, join_date := dateRep]
# rolling join
df<-uk_cases[policy_uk, on = .(join_date), roll = "nearest"]

ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(data = uk_cases, aes(x = dateRep, y = cases), stat = "identity") + 
  geom_text(data = df, aes(x = Date, y = cases, label = policy)) +
  scale_x_date(breaks = "1 month", minor_breaks = "1 week", labels=date_format("%B"))
```